# fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address

Tags: github-actions, github-pages

I'm currently starting to learn how to use Github Actions, and I ran into an authentification issue, where Github is able to retreive my username, but not my password, here's the error (the error occured on **Deploy to GH Pages**) :

```
create mode 100644 static/media/flow.edad2ac1.svg
create mode 100644 static/media/plugin.d494b228.svg
create mode 100644 static/media/repo.6d496322.svg
create mode 100644 static/media/stackalt.dba9fbb3.svg
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address
```

I was trying to deploy to GH Pages, here's the code :

```
  deployToGhPages:
    name: Deploy to GH Pages
    needs: [lint, tests]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: cache
        with:
          path: |
            node_modules
            */*/node_modules
          key: ${{ secrets.CACHE_VERSION }}-${{ runner.os }}-yarn-cache-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}

      - name: Yarn Build
        run: yarn build
      - name: Build Storybook
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: yarn build-storybook
      - name: Deploy to GH pages
        uses: nicoinch/ghpages@v3.0.0-alpha-1
        env:
          BUILD_DIR: storybook-static/
          GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

First ever question here, if I forgot to include any information, let me know !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update here ! (Yeah, that was quick)

When using **nicoinch/ghpages@v3.0.0-alpha-1** (page [here](https://github.com/nicoinch/ghpages)), you are requested to use a PAT (Private Access Token) to make it work.

I updated my code to this :

```
- name: Deploy to GH pages
        uses: nicoinch/ghpages@v3.0.0-alpha-1
        env:
          BUILD_DIR: storybook-static/
          GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
```

I created a PAT for my Github Account (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)) and placed it in the secrets of the repo (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets)), the secret being named **GH_PAT**.

Funny how I instantly found the answer after asking it on StackOverflow, I actually spent more than 10 hours searching for this solution, haha.